# Dynamically configuring java beans based on property file in Spring

Tags: spring, properties, javabeans

Wondering if there is a way to dynamically instantiate beans based on set of values in your property file using PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer class.

I have a java bean say Student with two attributes: "name" and "subject"

I have a property file with:

```
student.1.name=student1name
student.1.subject=student1subject
student.2.name=student2name
student.2.name=student2subject
```

Now I have a Classroom object that can take a list of students.

I am wondering if there is a way we could do this using Spring. The challenge here is that the number of students could vary.

If there was only one student object then:

```
<bean id="student" class="com.abc.Student">
    <property name="name" value="${student.1.name}" />
    <property name="subject"
        value="${student.1.subject}" />
</bean>

<bean id="classRoom" class="com.abc.ClassRoom">
    <property name="student" ref="student" />
</bean>
```

would have worked. But in this case we have a list of n Students. And the value of n could vary depending on the number of entries in the properties file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm with Kevin--IMO you're going about this the wrong way.

One possible workaround would be to create a bean that takes the property file as an argument, reads it in, and exposes a list of students (which would need to be indexed on *something*, like the *n* in the existing property file).

The classroom bean could then use that list of students.

But it sure looks like you're trying to duplicate the functionality of a DB, without a DB, in an awkward way.

Comment: Thanks for your input Kevin and Dave. I had this implemented taking property file as argument and instantiating the objects. Could have used XML as Kevin suggested, but thought it might be an overkill. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to do that with PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer. Usually when I have a situation like that I choose a configuration format of either JSON or XML and use GSON/Jackson/JAXB to unmarshall the data into objects.